A probability inequality and Boole's law for uncountably infinite sets
We can show a probability inequality of the form
$$ P(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n > \epsilon) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(x_i > \epsilon/n)$$
using Boole's law, which states that
$$ P(\cup_i A_i) \leq \sum_i P(A_i)$$
where $\{A_i\}$ are some events.
Boole's law does not hold for uncountable unions, which makes me think that we cannot get a continuous version of the first inequality:
$$ P \left(\int_0^1 X_t \,dt > \epsilon\right) \leq \int_0^1 P( X_t > \epsilon)\,dt \,,$$
where $X$ is a process on $[0,1]$.
Are there conditions under which this would hold?

While I can technically answer this, the last equation isn't really about probabilities. There is no random variable, so the probability can only ever evaluate to $0$ or $1$.

right.... let's say $x$ is a random variable. edited

but it's already the variable of integration

No, your continuous version is not going to work. Let’s look at an example where $X_t$ has a single almost sure realization,
$$ X_t = \begin{cases} 
100, & 0 \leq t < 1/2 \\ 
0, & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1 
\end{cases}.$$
Now let $\epsilon = 1$. The left hand side is
$$P(\int_0^1 X_t dt > \epsilon) = P(50 > \epsilon) = 1.$$
The right hand side is
$$\int_0^1 P(X_t > \epsilon) dt = \int_0^1  1*\chi_{t \leq 1/2} + 0* \chi_{t \geq 1/2} dt = 1/2.$$
Here $X_t$ was essentially deterministic. It is clear that we could make it non-deterministic by selecting a process that is, with high probability, big for a short while and small for the rest of the while. You guarantee that the left hand side is close to one, while the right hand side is small.

This is not interesting, as the process is not continuous. Note the question is if the inequality holds under certain conditions, not if the inequality always holds. On the other hand, if the inequality fails for continuous processes, that would be interesting.

First, the question was not about processes with continuous sample paths, the question was about continuous time processes. I think . Second, there is so much room between 1/2 and 1. Just do some fiddling and make $X_t$ continuous.

Third, let's consider the Poisson process with rate $\lambda=1$, $N_t$. Let $\epsilon = 1/4$. We have that
$$P[\int_0^1 N_t dt > 1/4] \geq P[N_{1/2} \geq 1] = 1 - P[N_{1/2} = 0] = 1 - e^{-1/2} \approx 0.39.$$
Also,
$$\int_0^1 P[N_t > 1/4] dt = \int_0^1 1 - P[N_t = 0] dt = \int_0^1 1 - e^{-t} dt = e^{-1} \approx 0.36.$$
So we have that the inequality doesn't hold for a fairly basic continuous time process. If you really want this process to have continuous sample paths, do something with approximate delta functions when defining the process $N_t$.
